# How to change/remove the Ubuntu version overlay from the lock screen?

Tags: 16.04, customization

The Ubuntu lock screen has the following overlay. How can I disable it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the logo/text used by the Unity Greeter, you can edit or replace the file found at `/usr/share/unity-greeter/logo.png`.

One simple way to remove the logo altogether would be to replace the image with a transparent one.